# Injetar dependências no construtor de um EJB pode causar problemas de modularização e performance?

Tags: java-ee, ejb, cdi

Faz pouco tempo que migrei do Spring para o CDI + EJB, tentei injetar minhas dependências diretamente no construtor assim como eu fazia no Spring e como é suportado pelo CDI porém em um EJB:

```java
@Stateless
public class UserService {

     private UserDao userDao;

     @Inject
     public UserService(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
     }
...
}
```

E me deparei com a especificação do EJB que obriga a criação de um construtor sem argumentos, fazendo com que o código acima não funcione enquanto tal construtor não for criado.

Após criar o segundo construtor (sem argumentos) e executar a aplicação percebi que a aplicação utilizou o construtor com argumentos nas injeções deste EJB possuindo o comportamento da forma que eu esperava.

Minha dúvida é: se meus EJBs construídos desta forma forem um dia expostos para outros sistemas via lookup/JNDI iriam utilizar o construtor sem argumentos ou passariam pelo outro construtor injetando as dependências?

E também não menos importante: o servidor de aplicação instancia em memória, neste caso que possuo dois construtores, EJBs com as dependências injetadas e outros sem as dependências?

O primeiro caso sei que sim pois o CDI faz o gerenciamento e vai instanciando de acordo com a demanda, mas o segundo caso de instanciar EJBs sem as dependências (usando o construtor sem argumentos) não sei dizer qual é comportamento. Principalmente pelo fato de eu ter colocado um `System.out` nos dois construtores e os dois foram chamados me preocupando pois haveria objetos desnecessários sendo gerenciados pelo servidor.

Comment: Você está usando transações JTA (gerenciadas pelo container) ou outro recurso que exija a anotação `@Stateless`? Se não, você pode simplesmente remover esta anotação e ao injetar `UserService` você pode usar a anotação `@Inject` em vez de `@EJB`. Deste modo você estará usando apenas injeção CDI e fica dispensado do construtor não parametrizado exigido pela anotação @EJB.

Comment: Acabo de descobrir que, se você puder usar JavaEE 7, você pode ter transações automaticamente gerenciadas usando a anotação `@Transactional`. Sua pergunta é muito bacana (eu também gostaria de entender estas duas instâncias que você está obtendo) mas o fato é que se você não usar a anotação `@EJB` você fica livre deste comportamento... "curioso", por assim dizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

desculpem a demora para responder esta questão pois alguns dias depois desta minha dúvida levei este questionamento para um ex-professor meu da Caelum que sanou estas dúvidas. É o seguinte:

Para resolver possíveis problemas em injetar objetos de escopo menor em objetos de escopo maior, como por exemplo injetar um objeto com escopo de request em um objeto com escopo de session, o que não faria sentido pois a dependência morreria antes do objeto principal, o CDI trabalha com proxies.

Sendo assim quando é realizada uma injeção (@Inject) o que de fato é injetado é um objeto criado pelo CDI (um proxy) que herda da minha classe concreta que deveria ser injetada ou que implementa a interface no caso da injeção ser de uma interface.

Então no meu caso o CDI cria uma instância do meu EJB sem dependências para usar como proxy (assim sendo por isso que meu EJB sem construtor é chamado) e injeta este proxy onde for solicitado o meu EJB via @Inject. Quando for chamado um método deste proxy, ele busca o EJB original (aquele que é criado via o construtor que possui as dependências) e invoca o método deste EJB original.

Agradeço ao Victor Harada por me esclarecer esta dúvida e assim eu podendo responder aqui também.